# Android studio does detect false SDK version

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

If i want to start my application in Android Studio, the dialogue opens to choose a running device;

But i get this error:

[image]

[image]

But my device is running on `Android 5.1.1` (Huawei Ascend P7).

Where is my fault?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "de.sese7.zooapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: What's your `compileSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in your gradle file? Post that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps necessary:
First you should Restart adb by typing the two console commands 'adb kill-server' and then 'adb start-server'.
Second turn on and off usb debugging on your phone
Third reboot your phone
And if it neither work reset your PC keys

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

- Restart adb by issuing 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb start-server' at a cmd prompt
- Disable and re-enable USB debugging on the phone
- Rebooting the phone if it still doesn't work.
- Resetting the PC-Keys